# Verify data on a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.7

I'm trying to make my life easier on my work, and writing down errors and solutions for that same errors. The program itself works fine when it's about adding new errors, but then I added a function to verify if the error exists in the file and then do something to it (not added yet).

The function doesn't work and I don't know why. I tried to debug it, but still not able to find the error, maybe a conceptual error?

Anyway, here's my entire code.

```
import sys
import os

err = {}
PATH = 'C:/users/userdefault/desktop/errordb.txt'

#def open_file():  #Not yet used
    #file_read = open(PATH, 'r')
    #return file_read

def verify_error(error_number, loglist): #Verify if error exists in file
    for error in loglist:
        if error_number in loglist:
            return True


def dict_error(error_number, solution): #Puts input errors in dict
    err = {error_number: solution}
    return err

def verify_file(): #Verify if file exists. Return True if it does
    archive = os.path.isfile(PATH)
    return archive

def new_error():
    file = open(PATH, 'r') #Opens file in read mode
    loglist = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    found = False
    error_number = input("Error number: ")
    if verify_error(error_number, loglist) == True:
        found = True
        # Add new solution, or another solution.
        pass
    solution = str(input("Solution: "))
    file = open(PATH, 'a')
    error = dict_error(error_number, solution)
    #Writes dict on file
    file.write(str(error))
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()

def main():
    verify = verify_file() #Verify if file exists
    if verify == True:
        new = str.lower(input("New job Y/N: "))
        if new == 'n':
            sys.exit()
        while new == 'y':
            new_error()
            new = str.lower(input("New job Y/N: "))
        else:
            sys.exit()
    else:
        file = open(PATH, "x")
        file.close()
        main()

main()
```

To clarify, the program executes fine, it don't return an error code. It just won't execute the way I'm intended, I mean, it supposed to verify if certain error number already exists.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add the error? :)

Comment: I don't have an error, the program executes fine, just not the way I'm intended :(

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I expect to, if I enter a repeated error number, the program verifies if that error exists inside the file, and if exists, return True. Right now the program runs the For loop and never returns True

Comment: *"conceptual error?"*: You are comparing, e.g. `123 == ["{'123':'test1'}", "{'456':'test2'}"]` which results `False`. Change to `if error_number in error:`. Beside this, it makes no sense to use a `dict` here. Read about [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I believe you're having is the fact that you're not actually creating a `dictionary object` in the file and modifying it but instead creating additional dictionaries every time an error is added then reading them back as a list of strings by using the `.readlines()` method.

An easier way of doing it would be to create a `dictionary` if one doesn't exist and append errors to it. I've made a few modifications to your code which should help.

```
import sys
import os
import json  # Import in json and use is as the format to store out data in

err = {}
PATH = 'C:/users/userdefault/desktop/errordb.txt'

# You can achieve this by using a context manager
#def open_file():  #Not yet used
    #file_read = open(PATH, 'r')
    #return file_read

def verify_error(error_number, loglist): #Verify if error exists in file
    # Notice how we're looping over keys of your dictionary to check if
    # an error already exists.
    # To access values use loglist[k]
    for k in loglist.keys():
        if error_number == k:
            return True
    return False

def dict_error(loglist, error_number, solution): #Puts input errors in dict
    # Instead of returning a new dictionary, return the existing one
    # with the new error appended to it 
    loglist[error_number] = solution
    return loglist

def verify_file(): #Verify if file exists. Return True if it does
    archive = os.path.isfile(PATH)
    return archive

def new_error():

    # Let's move all the variables to the top, makes it easier to read the function
    # Changes made:
    # 1. Changed the way we open and read files, now using a context manager (aka with open() as f:
    # 2. Added a json parser to store in and read from file in a json format. If data doesn't exist (new file?) create a new dictionary object instead
    # 3. Added an exception to signify that an error has been found in the database (this can be removed to add additional logic if you'd like to do more stuff to the error, etc)
    # 4. Changed the way we write to file, instead of appending a new line we now override the contents with a new updated dictionary that has been serialized into a json format
    found = False
    loglist = None

    # Open file as read-only using a context manager, now we don't have to worry about closing it manually
    with open(PATH, 'r') as f:
        # Lets read the file and run it through a json parser to get a python dictionary
        try:
            loglist = json.loads(f.read())
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            loglist = {}

    error_number = input("Error number: ")
    if verify_error(error_number, loglist) is True:
        found = True
        raise Exception('Error exists in the database')  # Raise exception if you want to stop loop execution
        # Add new solution, or another solution.

    solution = str(input("Solution: "))
    # This time open in write only and replace the dictionary
    with open(PATH, 'w') as f:
        loglist = dict_error(loglist, error_number, solution)
        # Writes dict on file in json format
        f.write(json.dumps(loglist))

def main():
    verify = verify_file() #Verify if file exists
    if verify == True:
        new = str.lower(input("New job Y/N: "))
        if new == 'n':
            sys.exit()
        while new == 'y':
            new_error()
            new = str.lower(input("New job Y/N: "))
        else:
            sys.exit()
    else:
        with open(PATH, "x") as f:
            pass
        main()

main()
```

Note that you will have to create a new `errordb` file for this snippet to work.

Hope this has helped somehow. If you have any further questions hit me up in the comments!

References:

- [Reading and Writing files in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [JSON encoder and decoder in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that there may be a couple of problems with your code, but the first thing that I noticed was that you are saving **Error Numbers** and **Solutions** as a dictionary in `errorsdb.txt` and when you read them back in you are reading them back in as a list of strings:

The line:

```py
loglist = file.readlines()
```

in `new_error` returns a list of strings. This means that `verify_error` will always return `False`.

So you have a couple of choices:

1. You could modify `verify_error` to the following:

```py
def verify_error(error_number, loglist): #Verify if error exists in file
    for error in loglist:
        if error_number in error:
            return True
```

2. Although, I think that a better solution would be to load `errorsdb.txt` as a JSON file and then you'll have a dictionary. That would look something like:

```py
import json

errordb = {}
with open(PATH) as handle:
    errordb = json.load(handle)
```

So here are the full set of changes I would make:

```py
import json

def verify_error(error_number, loglist): #Verify if error exists in file
    for error in loglist:
        if error_number in error:
            return True

def new_error():
    errordb = list()
    exitsting = list()
    with open(PATH) as handle:
        existing = json.load(handle)

    errordb += existing

    error_number = input("Error number: ")
    if verify_error(error_number, errordb) == True:
        # Add new solution, or another solution.
        print("I might do something here.")
    else:
        solution = str(input("Solution: "))
        errordb.append({error_number, solution})

    #Writes dict on file
    with open(PATH, "w") as handle:
        json.dump(errordb, handle)
```